# Is graceful restart of Apache forcing to reload all python modules handled by mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

If I want to be sure that all python modules are recompiled and reloaded in my Django project under mod_wsgi and Apache, is it enough to restart apache gracefully with:

```
/etc/init.d/apache graceful
```

or should I always do the full restart with

```
/etc/init.d/apache restart
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be as all processes are restarted.

See:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: Yes it should be what?